# F# in nativescript?

Tags: f#, nativescript

### How to use F# in nativescript?

We can write web apps with F# using https://fable.io/.

Since Nativescript can use Kotlin,  I was wondering **how** can we also use F# ?

I want to enable. `<script lang="fs" >`

In nativescript-vue I can use `<script lang="ts" >` to write in typescript.
Is it possible to use ` to write in F#_?

---

#### Functional programming and more

- Immutable by default.
- Powerful pattern matching.
- Lightweight syntax.
- Units of measure.
- Type providers.

Comment: The more common .NET alternative to NativeScript is Xamarin. See https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-and-xamarin

Comment: I looked at using fable and nativescript but I found it to be a bit involved and opted to use fable with cordova instead which was much easier to implement. You can basically just use your public folder from fable as your assets in cordova with some minor modifications.

Comment: @onemorecupofcoffee can you please write it in Answer form.

Answer (score 3):

NativeScript apps are built using JavaScript, or by using any language that transpiles to JavaScript,so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fable, you will have your F# that transpiles to Javascript and use the JS it generated for your Nativescript code.

> Fable produces readable JavaScript code compatible with ES2015 standards and popular tooling like Webpack!

https://fable.io/